# Specific Reference? Noncommutative topology and C^* algebras

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, noncommutative-geometry, banach-algebras, noncommutative-topology

I stumbled across this "dictionary for noncommutative topology" http://planetmath.org/noncommutativetopology
and I would be very interested in learning more on the subject, particularly I'd like to see why these results are true.

What is the reference to the results in section 3 of the above linked page?

Comment: MathOverflow is better suited to specific questions or requests, rather than general "tell me more about X" requests. Could you try to change your question to something more focused? See "MO is not an encyclopaedia", http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic

Comment: I doubt if there is a single reference for all the entries of the table in the above link. Perhaps, you should try to understand the Gelfand duality first and then try to prove these equivalences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Les C$^*$-algèbres et leurs représentations* (answers most of these).

Find it [here](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CDgQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fiecl.univ-lorraine.fr%2F~Nicolas.Prudhon%2Fgnc%2Fbibliographie%2FOperator%2520Algebras%2FDixmier%2520%5B1977a%2C%2520288pp%5Dh---C-star-algebras.pdf&ei=_vHHU8jvAtCgyAS7qoAw&usg=AFQjCNEw7EMCQDbfHD9TKhg8VAvQF1qTLw&bvm=bv.71198958,d.aWw&cad=rja). That "dictionary" can also be found [here](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CFQQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.aalto.fi%2Fopetus%2Fharmanal%2Fpruju%2Fcalg04.pdf&ei=CPXHU4W7N5K3yASQrYCgBg&usg=AFQjCNEwD0IBkTU17mU6IcFfV5BNqLdENg&sig2=r4ukgeWZhIAVIXaRlgsD6A&bvm=bv.71198958,d.aWw&cad=rja).

Comment: I should point out for others reading that Dixmier's book is for learning about general Cstar algebras in some depth, and not about the "noncommutative topology" correspondence mentioned in the question. For instance, I don't recall Dixmier's book discussing compactifications of spaces as corresponding to unitizations of algebras.

Comment: No but he does give some of the correspondences, the unitization result is found everywhere for example in Conway's Functional analysis.

Comment: Sure, my point is that Dixmier's book is somewhat "of its time" and not what I would recommend for someone who is new to NCG. I'd recommend it for people who actually care about Cstar algebras, especially those of locally compact groups.

Answer (score 5):

Dixmier's book is a fine, if dated, introduction to C*-algebra, but really not the right place to learn about noncommutative topology. The place you want to go is Alain Connes' [Noncommutative Geometry](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf).

Edit: in response to Yemon's comment I might refer to my own book *Mathematical Quantization*. Most of the correspondences mentioned are covered in Section 5.1, and many others can be found throughout the book.

Comment: I think the OP may merely wish to know about the "dictionary" that is used to motivate NC(D)G, e.g. closed ideals in the ring correspond to open subsets in the space, and so on. But I am not certain, which is one reason for the comment I left on the original question

Answer (score 0):

K-Theory and C*-Algebras: A Friendly Approach (Oxford Science Publications)
by N.E. Wegge-Olsen.